# Promise does not seem to be calling resolve

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I have the following code:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const multerUploadWorker = async(req, res, storage) => {
    console.log('worker called');
    
    const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

    upload(req, res, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            return Promise.reject();
        } else {
            console.log('resolve called');
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    });
};

module.exports = multerUploadWorker;
```

and:

```
const { success, fail } = require('../utils/response-util');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerUploadWorker = require('../workers/multer-upload-worker');
const path = require('path');

const upload = async(req, res) => {

    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (_, _, cb) {
            cb(null, 'uploads/')
        },

        filename: function (_, file, cb) {
            const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);

            switch (ext) {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.JPG':
                case '.jpeg':
                case 'JPEG':
                case '.png':
                case '.PNG':
                case '.gif':
                case '.GIF':
                    cb(null, Date.now() + ext);
                    break;
                default:
                    cb('File type error', false);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });


    try {
        if (await multerUploadWorker(req, res, storage)) {
            return success(res, { message: req.file });
        }
    } catch(error) {
        return fail(
            res, 'Something went wrong, please check the image type is \
JPEG, GIF or PNG', '500'
        );
    }
};

module.exports = {
    upload
};
```

It seems that although the console logs `resolve called` inside `multerUploadWorker` it doesn't trigger the `if (await multerUploadWorker(req, res, storage))` condition. No error is thrown, just nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A return to an inner function does not return to an outer function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of Promises is incorrect. `multerUploadWorker` should return promise but in your case it returns nothing.

```js
const multer = require('multer');

const multerUploadWorker = async(req, res, storage) => {
    console.log('worker called');
    
    const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        upload(req, res, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error)
        } else {
            console.log('resolve called');
            resolve();
        }
      });
    });
};

module.exports = multerUploadWorker;
```

Also the way you handle result, there is no need to check for result because you are not returning boolean, just wait for upload to finish and in case of error handle in `catch` statement:

```
    try {
       await multerUploadWorker(req, res, storage))
       return success(res, { message: req.file });
    }
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `multer ` library and not aware if `upload` returns Promise or just callback based.

Comment: `multer` is callback based

Comment: why am I using promises incorrectly? It's an async function I am returning one for reject and one for resolve. I have also tried your code and it's exactly the same result.

Comment: @Kex async function supposed to return Promise, in your case it returns nothing which is treated as if you return undefined immediately without waiting for actual upload to happen.

Comment: @Kex I have edited answer to include adjustment regarding usage.

Comment: Works! Thanks. Seems it was the two issues. 1) I was trying to return from inside a closure which doesn't work 2) My if statement was not needed just `await multerUploadWorker(req, res, storage)) `